# How do you configure php5 and Oracle for use with Yii?

Tags: php, oracle, yii, pdo

I had to install apache + php and configure it to work with an Oracle database.  I used the settings described in this article: http://habrahabr.ru/post/116474/.  However, when I use Yii, although results are returned, the column is in upper case despite the fact that I have set the attribute to lower case.

Comment: are the columns in Uppercase in the database it self?

Answer (score 1):

In oracle column names are internally case insensitive, which means oracle will always convert unescaped column names (and tables) into UPPERCASE and return resul sets (unfortunatelly) also in UPPERCASE. To prevent from this you have to quote column names (and table names). You can use function "Yii::app()->db->quoteColumnName($column);" for that.